# Windows 10 unable to connect to Ubuntu 20.04.3 Samba Server (0x80004005 Unspecified Error)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba

**My goal**: my windows 10 client can access, view, and execute .exe file shared by the Ubuntu server using guest account (Without password).

**Expected Result**: When I type \ubuntu-server-hostname\bakro in the file explorer, I can see and execute the .exe file

**Actual Result**: Windows cannot access \ubuntu-server-hostname\bakro with Error code: 0x80004005 Unspecified Error

**Additional Observations**:

1. When I run `net use \\ubuntu-server-hostname\bakro` on Windows 10 client, it results in `System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.`
2. I can access the shared files from the ubuntu server using smbclient.
   When I run `smbclient -L \\\\ubuntu-server-hostname`, I can see bakro listed there.
   When I run `smbclient \\\\ubuntu-server-hostname\\bakro` to enter the smb command line and I type `ls` to list the files inside the share, I can see the .exe file.
   In both of these cases, I was asked for my current user account password. I responded by pressing enter key (blank password).
   I checked the log by using `systemctl status smbd` and results in multiple lines of `session closed for user samba-guest`. The timing seems consistent with me acessing the share via `smbclient`.
3. The ubuntu server is also running OpenVPN server. The OpenVPN server uses 10.8.0.0/24 subnet and is assigned 10.8.0.1 ip address. If I connect to the OpenVPN server using the same Windows 10 computer and then access the samba share by typing `\\10.8.0.1` in the file explorer, I can see the folder bakro listed. I can browse the folder and execute the .exe file (which is my desired and expected result). This access attempt is recorded in the samba log using `systemctl status smbd`.

**What I have done:**

- Based on Observation #1, I replaced the hostname with server public ip address. It yields the same result for accessing via both `net use` and file explorer. Both attempts are not recorded in samba log obtained via `systemctl status smbd`.
- Based on Observation #1 and #2, I checked the Ubuntu server firewall using `ufw status`. Samba is listed as allowed via both ipv4 and ipv6. I also checked the server's security group. Port 445 TCP is listed as allowed.
  I have tried disabling ufw and setting security group to allow connection to all ports from anywhere and I still can't access the share.
- Based on Observation #3, I obtained a list of network interfaces using `ip link show`. 3 interfaces are obtained: lo (loopback), eth0 (internet), tun0 (OpenVPN). I added `interfaces = lo eth0` into smb.conf. The result: I cannot access the share from both `\\ubuntu-server-hostname\bakro` and `\\10.8.0.1\bakro`.
- I tried changing the guest account from samba-guest to nobody. Nothing changed except the log now shows `session closed for user nobody` instead.
- I tried adding `client min protocol = SMB2` and `client max protocol = SMB3` to smb.conf [source](https://serverfault.com/questions/720332/cannot-connect-to-linux-samba-share-from-windows-10)
- Changed File sharing connections to enable 40 and 56 bit encryption in Advanced sharing settings in Windows 10 client.

**Minor Observation:**

- I swear I tested the file sharing capabilities using the same Windows 10 computer when I first setup the samba service (But my memory is unreliable at best)
- I also tried to access \ubuntu-server-hostname\bakro via file explorer on 2 other Windows 7 computer with same result.

The following are the contents of my smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        disable netbios = Yes
        guest account = samba-guest
        interfaces = 0.0.0.0/0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        security = USER
        server role = standalone server
        server string = ubuntu-samba-server
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[bakro]
        guest ok = Yes
        path = /srv/files/bakro
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: did you get this working? it seems I have a very similiar problem

Answer (score 0):

Everything is changing slowly. I have been using for more than 15 years very silmple smb.conf but suddenly it was not possible to connect to a share as guest. If I configured the home-dir share, it was OK, but the free share for guest was denied. It took me some time to find that in the share definition it is necessary to specify: `valid users = nobody` as you can see in the example:

```
[data]
path          = /srv/data
valid users   = nobody
force user    = nobody
read list     = nobody
write list    = nobody
guest account = nobody
guest only    = yes
guest ok      = yes
```

I cannot explain, why and how it is function. Just know, it is dependent on on samba version (now: 4.11.5-Debian).
The dir /srv/data on linux side should have nobody:nogroup and at least 666 for files and 777 for dirs. Hence the `create mask = 666` and `directioy mask = 777` could be useful. In this way you should correct the global settings.